# UIActivityIndicator in UIWebView for Live Video(.mjpg)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4, uiwebview

I am streaming a live video(.mjpg) using UIWebView like:

```
[liveVideoPlayer loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

where liveVideoPlayer is an instance of custom UIWebView. Problem i am facing is that for low bandwidth the frame rate for the video reduced by a good number and seems that the video is paused.I just want to add an UIActivityIndicator at that time to tell  user that its streaming time until we get the next frame.

I can't use Delegate methods `– webViewDidStartLoad:
– webViewDidFinishLoad:` because for live video webViewDidFinishLoad never been called.Need help to solve that please help...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depending on the type of protocol, you might be able to use a MPMoviePlayerController, you would then be able to register for notifications. I don't think there is a solution to your problem as it is.

Comment: thanks jbat100 for responding.but need to display multiple video here. MPMoviePlayerController doesn't support that.still waiting....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...here i got a temporary solution for now. I've added UIActivityIndicatorView behind the UIwebView and keep it animating. Better than previous stage, not cent percent but quit enough for now.Looking for the better one...